# cannot convert .text to int in SQL method

Tags: c#, database

I try every method it can be convert .text to int but I got error like this.

mycode

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=libralyServer;Integrated Security=True");
            con1.Open();             
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into bookData values(@bookName,@bookWriter,@bookTotel)", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookName", textBox1.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookWriter", textBox2.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookTotel",int.Parse(textBox2.Text));//have error
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con1.Close();
        }
```

[image]

how to fix it? I try to search many how to on internet, but I still can't fix this error.

Comment: no image, text please

Comment: I assume it's a typo as you use `textBox2.Text` twice; maybe you intended to write `int.Parse(textBox3.Text)`? Better control names would definitely help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear from the exception message that `textBox2.Text` is not a valid integer value, you have to first check whether it's valued int or not. you can use `int.TryParse` method. It returns `false` if the string is not convertible to an integer value.

Here is the official documentation.

Few points to be noted here.

Please don't define the connection string directly in the C# file. you can define it in the config file.

Please use `using` statement with the connection and command.

You can also utilize the return value of `ExeceuteNonQuery` method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0

Comment: Why explore SQL Injection?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama just implement the data validation if it's not already implemented

Comment: I mean... OP's code is already safe from SQL injection. I don't understand why you're suggesting exploring it as a solution to their current problem...

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama let me remove that point, that was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, textbox2.Text is equal to "s". This is not something that int.Parse() is able to turn into an integer, therefore throwing an exception.

You can use int.TryParse() to attempt to parse the string value and if it fails, do something else.